# How can I successfully pass a variable into my sqlite SELECT statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am writing a small program that lets me search a sqlite database, `assets` by asset number, serial number, etc. The problem is that I'm not sure has to pass user input, a variable `assetNum`, into my sqlite `SELECT` statement. I would like it to take the user-queried `assetNum` and return that row from the sqlite table.

First, I defined my function:

```
def search_asset_num(conn):

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM assets WHERE AssetNumber = '{}'".format(assetNum))

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

In the program I utilize user-input to move through menus, so later on in the program when I get to the "search by asset menu" I have:

```
   elif selection == '2':

            menu2 = {}
            menu2['        1'] = "Search Assets by Name"
            menu2['        2'] = "Search Assets by Asset Number"
            menu2['        3'] = "Search Assets by Serial Number"
            menu2['        4'] = "Search Assets by Ownership"
            menu2['        5'] = "Go back!"

            choices2 = menu2.keys()
            for entry in choices2:
                print(entry, menu2[entry])

            selection2 = input("Enter number: ")

            if selection2 == '2':

                assetNum = input("Enter Asset Number: ")

                search_asset_num(conn)
```

The problem, from what I can tell, is that `assetNum` is present in the `search_asset_num()` function above where it is actually defined in the `if` statement as `assetNum = input("Enter Asset Number: ")`. I'm not sure how to work around this. I have tried making `assetNum` global at the very top of my code and setting it to equal `0` as a placeholder, but that did not work. It just outputs `0` to the terminal.

Comment: pass as an extra argument? `search_asset_num(conn,assetNum )` You do not need global variable in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `assetNum` as parameter to your function,

```
def search_asset_num(conn, assetNum):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM assets WHERE AssetNumber = ?", (assetNum,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

in your menu, you can change as below:

```
        if selection2 == '2':
            assetNum = input("Enter Asset Number: ")
            search_asset_num(conn, assetNum)
```

also use "Parameter Substitution" as stated in [Python sqlite3 - DB-API documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: I just tried this with `(assetNum,)`,  and the code ran but no rows were returned. Is it not executing my `for row in rows` loop? I added a quick `print(assetNum)` to test within the `def search_asset_num()` function and it printed my input.

Comment: please try for debugging purpose directly write your asset number in query, for example `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM assets WHERE AssetNumber = 'ABC'")`) or just `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM assets")` to be sure that you are connecting to correct database

Comment: That worked, and your entire answer worked, thanks. I was being stupid and initially typed in the wrong input number but I verified that it is now working.

Comment: @Nan, no problems, but I suggest you start learning python from some source, because this question is just basics, you can start from [Official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Roger that! I'll check it out.